# Test Automation for Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, automated-tests, gui-testing

Is there any tools for GUI Test Automation for Internet Explorer?
I already use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) for Mozilla Firefox, but I also need a tool for IE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*** UPDATE Feb 2020 ***

[Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) is a new tool for browser testing and one of the few tools that doesn't use Selenium under the hood.  [It does NOT, however, support Internet Explorer](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/launching-browsers.html#Unsupported-Browsers).  It does support Microsoft Edge and many other modern browsers, so hopefully it helps some people.

*** UPDATE (older) ***

[Selenium Web Driver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) is the successor to Selenium RC.

So the answer is still to use [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) in some form.  That could be any of the [supported frameworks](http://www.seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.jsp#programming-languages).

Personally I'd use [Protractor](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/) (useful for more than just Angular apps) or [Leadfoot](https://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/index.html) (from the [Intern.io](https://theintern.github.io/) project).

---

*** ORIGINAL RECOMMENDATION ***

If you're already using Selenium, I'd use [Selenium Remote Control](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/)

Comment: Sorry, but I need to downvote this since the Feb 2020 update is currently irrelevant to the question:  https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/launching-browsers.html#Unsupported-Browsers If I am wrong, please let me know and I will upvote this back up.

Comment: @papiro You are correct.  This question was asked almost 10 years ago.  I figure most people have moved on to only supporting Edge, so I feel it still sticks with the spirit of the question.  I'll accept the downvote if you feel that strongly.

Comment: I would mention something like that in your update. Otherwise it's confusing. I legitimately came here looking for an IE11 solution, which is still quite common. It sent me on a wild goose hunt to Cypress. Glad to learn more about Cypress, but not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can still use selenium for IE Explorer. I don't know if there is a plugin, but that shouldn't stop you. You'll get a lot of benifit from using the same tool to test on all browsers, so I would think you would be better served to learn how to use selenium with IE Explorer rather than trying to re-implement all your tests in another tool

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the automated UI testing facilities of Microsoft Test Manager, which is part of Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You may be after something like this: **http://triflejs.org/** (currently in beta)

Its an IE port of [phantomjs](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs) for running Headless UI tests... basically an alternative to WebDriver but using javascript files instead of Java/NET compiled code.

If you combine [TrifleJS](http://triflejs.org) (IE), [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org) (Webkit: Chrome + Safari) and [SlimerJS](http://slimerjs.org) (Firefox) you can run headless tests in all common browser environments using the same test scripts and API.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net). I have had decent success using it with IE.

http://watin.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 0):

There are several GUI Test Automation tools for web application that run on IE. A few examples are [Rational Functional Tester](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/tester/functional/), [Etester](http://www.testapps.com/etester.asp) and [QTP](http://www.testapps.com/quicktestpro.asp).

If you are looking for something open source there look [here](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/functional.php)

Not sure about any add on plugin tool like selenium that is available for IE.

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck with [watir](http://watir.com/), it's similar to selenium but is scripted in ruby. It's IE integration is excellent. There's also [firewatir](http://code.google.com/p/firewatir/) for firefox.

Answer (score 0):

[TestPlan](http://testplan.brainbrain.net/) can use the Selenium backend and works with both FireFox and Internet Explorer. It can also work with a display-less browser (HTMLUnit) so you can code your basic tests quickly and not suffer the loading overhead of the browser. Once it basically works you test it against the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try coding in AutoIt this is powerfull language easy to learn.
[IE UDF is here](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/149526-librariesieau3/)

Answer (score 0):

If your browser is IE,going for test automation is not a very good decision.You may face so many issues with IE browser in automation.But still you can use selenium web driver for automation in IE.