# Click button is not working for ie browser while executing from Laptop

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am facing a strange issue that Click Button "locator" is not working for ie browser when I am executing from laptop (ie, not connected to an external monitor). It identifies and move to the next step but not clicking it.
Catching point is, If I try to connect my laptop to a monitor, the code works for IE as well. Its not working only when I am running the script from laptop. Same code working fine in Chrome in laptop.
Has anyone faced the same issue, do I need to do any resolution setting?

I am using robot framework + Python + selenium. Sample code given below -

${btn_Login}        //*[@id="btnLogin"]
Click Button    ${btn_Login}

Comment: What is the browser in your laptop that your code is failing? Did you use proper code spaces for robot framework (a tab space between each keyword and arguments)?
Please post more code leading to the error. It is difficult to come to a solution with just one line of code that you pasted. Also, please paste in code block format. Thanks!

Comment: As mentioned, I am using IE browser.
This is not related to my code as its working fine in Chrome. If I open the browser in Chrome, code works fine without any changes.

Comment: Understood now. IE seems almost deprecated and is pretty unstable with selenium as far as I know. You may check this link and get some answers/ideas here: [SO archive link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40739097/robot-framework-selenium2library-ie11-is-very-unstable-to-complete-tests)

Comment: Catching point is, If I try to connect my laptop to a monitor, the code works for IE as well. Its not working only when I am running the script from laptop.

Answer (score 2):

Its running in IE after changing the Scale and layout to 100% under display setting.